# Facebook like automatic image crop with intelligent results

Tags: php, facebook, crop

I have noticed that every image I upload to Facebook is cropped automatically for the thumbnails. By automatically I mean that the user is not involved in setting the crop params in any way. The thing that is bugging me is that even with auto crop the thumbnails Facebook gets in the end are intelligent (they somehow crop the exact area where the face or the figure of the person is). How is that possible and how to do it in PHP?

P.S.
I can't install install things to the server. And even without a face detection is there someway to make a good guess. I have noticed that for larger images facebook requires manual crops and does auto crop only for smaller images. **The main goal is to make smart square crops and then resize them for thumbnails.**

Comment: Side note, I think FB also does some resizing client-side.  There are some good free tools for this like Plupload (http://www.plupload.com/index.php) but it doesn't have any "smart" cropping.

Comment: I'm doing resizing right now, but I want to crop before the resize :) The main goal is to make all thumbs square and then resize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also a jquery plugin which can do face detection so you could use the coordinates that it comes up with in a php script to crop the image.
http://papermashup.com/jquery-face-detection/

Answer (score 1):

Probably they are parsing the image with an algorithm for face-object detection.

http://corpocrat.com/2009/08/18/automatic-face-detection-with-php-in-linux/

Comment: take a look at the P.S. Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what facebook does but i'm pretty sure this is possible through "Face Detection" like in any Digital Camera these days.

I think this is what you're searching for:

http://www.xarg.org/project/php-facedetect/

but you need to be able to install add-ons to the server. I think if you want to do this through phl you will allways have to install something on the server.